# Como pegar a posição atual de um div por sua classe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Por exemplo:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="position"></div> <!-- Essa tinha que ser position [0]-->
  <div class="position"></div> <!-- Essa tinha que ser position [1]-->
  <div class="other"></div>
  <div class="position"></div> <!-- Essa tinha que ser position [2]-->
  <div class="position"></div> <!-- Essa tinha que ser position [3]-->
  <div class="other"></div>
  <div class="position"></div> <!-- Essa tinha que ser position [4]-->
  <div class="other"></div>
  <div class="other"></div>
</div>
```

Isso feito de preferencia com Jquery.

É possível?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar assim:

```
var divs = $('.container .position');
divs.each(function (i) {
    this.setAttribute('data-index', i);
});
divs.on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this).data('index'));
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/MkLkp/)

No caso de querer saber qual é a ultima div pode usar [**assim**](http://jsfiddle.net/MkLkp/1/)

---

**Existe outra variante:**

```
var divs = $('.container .position');
divs.on('click', function () {
   var pos = (divs.get()).indexOf(this);
   // ou, à la Zuulvaretto:
   // var pos = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(divs, this);
    console.log(pos);
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/LsD7k/)

Comment: Sergio, tem como adicionar por exemplo um .css() atravez de seu index. Assim, quero adicionar um background onde o index é 4.. tipo $(".position").index(4).css("background", "red"), tipo manipular pelo seu index()

Comment: @JeffersonAlison, sim. Pode usar assim: __[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G37cB/)__ -  `$(".position").eq(4).css("background-color", "red");`

Comment: @JeffersonAlison, e pondo as duas a interagir: http://jsfiddle.net/u5m89/1/

Comment: Um refactoring à la Zuul pra você: http://jsfiddle.net/LsD7k/1/

Comment: Hahaha :) gostei do _" à la Zuul"_ @bfavaretto

Comment: Hahahaha, *Zuulvaretto* :)

Comment: Opa.. Isso mesmo.. deu certinho! Obrigadissimo!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode selecionar os elementos via jQuery. O array estará na [ordem que estes aparecem no DOM](http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/).

```
$(".position").each(function(index, el) {
    $(this).text("Pos: " + index);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27Rg7/)

Comment: Entendi! Obrigado.

Comment: Ok, amigo.. e fazendo isso com click? Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/27Rg7/1/  Ao clicar no primeiro ele mostra a posição dele e assim por diante. Ao chegar no ultimo imprimir "Eu sou o ultimo". Esse exemplo esta assim: ao clicar no primeiro ele mostra de todos, queria que mostrasse so a posição dele.

Comment: @JeffersonAlison Eu faria [assim](http://jsfiddle.net/27Rg7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `index()` do jQuery, funcionando da seguinte forma, no seu caso vou exemplificar com um evento de clique:

```
$('.position').click(function(){
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

Comment: `$(this).index()` vai dar o index relativo a todas as divs, incluíndo `.other`. Dê uma olhada na 4a div __[aqui.](http://jsfiddle.net/BpFTy/1/)__

Comment: Tava aqui me perguntando: quando será que o Sergio vai aparecer pra falar que tá errado? hahaha, brincadeira. (mas eu sabia que tava porém confesso que fiquei com preguiça rs)

Comment: haha :) apanhei por acaso, fui saír e estava a dar uma olhada às perguntas que tinha "perdido"

Comment: pois então, eu tava pensando em pegar o index com o clique mas não consegui pensar em uma coisa que funcionasse certinho.

Comment: Veio-me agora à cabeça uma alternativa: `($('.position').get()).indexOf(this);`